# Node.JS API project errror

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

I'm building my first API web project and I have encountered an error:

```
return expressJwt({
           ^
TypeError: expressJwt is not a function
```

This is my code :

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret;

    return expressJwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
    })
module.exports = authJwt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are importing the whole module, you have to specify the method to use. For example:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret;

    return expressJwt.expressjwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
    })
  }
```

Comment: This will work well.

Comment: you are right it worked out, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you are not using correctly `express-jwt` when you do

> const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

You are importing the all **library**, however, you need specifically `expressJwt` method, so you can do something like

```js
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret;

    return expressJwt.expressjwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
    })
```

Or even better, as explained in the official documentation

```js
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
    const secret = process.env.secret;

    return jwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
    })
```

Comment: This wont work. `expressJwt` does not exist as a key in the exported module. Object keys are case sensitive.

Comment: @jQueeny yes you are right, there was a typo in my key, i'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module in Node.js you need to know what is being exported by the module.

You are using the [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) module with CommonJS syntax which exports an object with a key of `expressjwt` and the value of which is a function named `expressjwt`. It looks like this:

```js
exports.expressjwt = expressjwt;

// This is what's exported: { expressjwt: expressjwt }
```

If you want to use the `expressjwt` function then you can use [object destructing](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) to import it like so:

```js
const { expressjwt } = require("express-jwt");
```

If you want to rename the `expressjwt` function when you import it you can. The official docs give an example of renaming it to `jwt` like this:

```js
var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");
```

To get your code working you can rename `expressjwt` to `expressJwt` very easily like this:

```js
const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require("express-jwt");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your assistance.